# How can I delete the application after it upon closing it?

Tags: python, python-3.x

How to delete python executable file after it finishes? I have tried the following:

- `os.remove()` - deleting the python exe file
- `os.chmod()` - removing the readOnly
- `os.getcwd` - combined with `os.remove()`
- `shutile.rmtree` - combined with `os.getcwd()`
- `sys.argv[0]`

All of these works when I still use `.py` extension, but when I convert it to `exe` it gives me permission error. How do I remove it?

I want to delete the `main.exe` because I'm going to distribute it to my friends. I don't want the program to stay inside their system permanently that's why I decided to create an auto-delete script.

The code I'm running revolves under pyqt5.

Comment: This depends on the operating system. Which one are you using?

Comment: windows10 -  64bit

Comment: You literally mean `python.exe`? How would you run python code if you remove that?

Comment: no, not python.exe. what I meant was the main.py converted to main.exe using pyinstaller. sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1):

you can achieve this by creating a separate bat file, and calling that after executing your code

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
    cleanup()
```

here is the cleanup function

```
import os
import sys

def cleanup():
    with open("cleanup.bat", "w+") as file:
        file.write(f"DEL /F \"{sys.argv[0]}\" \nDEL /F \"{os.getcwd()}\\cleanup.bat\"")
    os.startfile(os.getcwd()+"\\cleanup.bat")
```

Answer (score 0):

1. I would start with ensuring that what you are trying to do is what you actually need. If you provide more details about your real purpose, probably we could find a better solution without using strange workarounds and/or crutches to solve your problem
2. In Windows 10 it is not possible to remove an executable when it is running (no matter whether you are trying to remove the file from the inside or the outside of the executable), this is why you are getting permission error with the .exe file. Probably there is some workaround which would use some special Windows-only features (because as far as I'm concerned it's not possible to do what you are asking about with libraries such as `threading`/`multiprocessing`), but if you **really want** to do this, the easiest way I see is using another executable intended specifically to delete the executable which calls it after the original executable finishes.

But, again, this is not a good solution and to be honest, I don't think there is a perfect one, because your goal seems an anti-pattern to me

Comment: I'm planning to create another executable file designated to delete the main.exe. but this is my last resort. Trying to find another solution that is under one executable file.

Comment: @mangoorange What about your real purpose? Why do you want to delete the executable after a run?

Comment: I have edited the body of my question. Since I will be distributing the executable file to my friends, I want the program to be one-time use only.

Comment: @mangoorange You can try to run a batch command that wait some seconds, in the meanwhile the python program ends, after the delay the batch command delete the .exe file. You can also try to run a new python instance (without a new .exe dedicated) just running `python.exe -c "myDelay + myDeleteCommand"`

Comment: @CarloZanocco okay, I'm going to try it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

i used one of the answers above that made a batch file that deleted the executable then itself which worked fine other than that the batch file open a console when it ran and as i dont know how to write batch files nor modify them i looked abit into vbs and came up with this function:

```
def self_delete():
    with open("deleting.vbs", "x") as vbs_file:
        vbs_file.write("On Error resume next:Do While True:"+
                       f"CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\").DeleteFile(\"{sys.executable}\"):"+
                       "If Err.Number <> 0 Then Err.Clear:Else Exit Do\n"+
                       "Loop:CreateObject(\"Scripting.FileSystemObject\").DeleteFile(Wscript.ScriptFullName)")
    os.startfile(f'{os.getcwd()}\\deleting.vbs')
```

which basically opens and writes on a .vbs file commands to delete the executable then itself, but for who want to know how it works step by step here's the explanation: first it opens a .vbs file and writes on it a command to not skip any line of code that throws an error upon running so it wont block all the rest of the code, then it makes a while True loop that keeps on trying to delete the executable but if it cant due to the permission error meaning the executable is still running it skips it then it the next lines it checks if any errors where thrown and skipped and if it finds any it just clears it and re-runs the loop but if no error was thrown and skipped it breaks out of the loop and goes to the next line of code and deletes itself (the .vbs file), note that the code is written in a one-line syntax mode to minimize the space it takes in the .py file but it runs the same it would without being in a one-line syntax
NOTE: its better to use this function at the end of the script or add "os._exit(0)" at the end of the function for it not to create the .vbs file and run it looping waiting for the python executable to close for it to be able to delete it, thought this is just for looks as creating a "deleting.vbs" in the directory of the python executable wont look so good so closing the executable right after making it wont even give it a chance of appearing in the directory, otherwise it would still work just fine if the executable still ran before closing due to its implemented error handling